# CSS Text alignment when vertical align is super

Tags: css, menu, vertical-alignment, super

I'm trying to develop a menu where dynamically some text must have the property vertical-align:super.
It's happening that this item containing "super" text is not vertical aligned with other item.

Here the CSS code:

```
<style>
  #menu{width:300px;height:100px;background:#ABD4E6;}
  #menu ul{list-style:none;}
  #menu li{float:left;background:#054664;padding:20px;}
</style>

<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>App<span style="vertical-align: super;">*</span></li>
    <li>Contacts</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

How can I solved the issue?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements with `float: left` behave in such way that they won't position themselves verticaly, no matter what `vertical-align` would you set to them. All `li` elements should not have `float: left` so they would preserve some specific line-height. Then you can position them together with the `span`, relatively to the line-height. One of the possibilities is to change the `#menu li` styles to this:

```css
#menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    background:#054664;
    padding:20px;
}
```

You will also have to remember to change the HTML markup a bit. There must be no white-spaces between each *opening* and *enclosing* `li` tags, like this:

```
  <ul>
    <li>
        Home
    </li><li><!-- HERE: no space -->
        App<span style="vertical-align: super;">*</span>
    </li><li><!-- HERE: no space also -->
        Contacts
     </li>
  </ul>
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/eLft6/

Answer (score 0):

I've another issues. The text in now vertically aligned but the position changed if I use span with super property or not.

Vertical alignment of this code:

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>App<span style="vertical-align: super;">*</span></li>
    <li>Test</li>
  </ul>
```

is different from that one:

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>App</li>
    <li>Test</li>
  </ul>
```

I've tried to modify the line-height using span for all **li** item, also setting it with different value in case of **super** usage or not but it doesn't work!